# Keystonejs load list's content on every page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

Is there an efficient way to load a Keystone's list's content on every page instead of calling it separately in each view? Perhaps in middlewear.js?

The goal is to make a drop down for the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`next()`

in your exports.initLocals middlewear with

`keystone.list('YOUR_MODEL').model.find().exec(
        function(err, result) {
            locals.fontsNav = result;
            next();
        }
    );`

and you can print them like you would any grouping

`each link in YOUR_MODEL
        li(class=(section == link.key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=link.href)= link.label`

To answer my own question... solved via https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/keystonejs/FDSpXb9qxyM/V_ue1sgrk2AJ